# Which feature to take in negative correlation?

Tags: correlation, feature-engineering

I know that if two features show highly positive correlation (lets say > 0.8), we take one in our ML model and leave the other. This I understand, as both are going in same direction. But if two features show highly negative correlation (< -0.8), how to select the features in this case? As I understand, as one feature will increase, the other will decrease. I mean to ask, how to interpret negative correlation (with respect to positive correlation) and how to apply this interpretation in our model while doing feature selection?

Comment: Negate one of the features, start over, and use what you know about positively correlated variables!

Comment: But negating will change the actual data, doesn't it? @whuber

Comment: Sure--but it's no different than, say, recording temperatures in degrees F and restating them in degrees C for analysis.  Besides, you're doing ML--why would you even care that the data are changed, provided the model works?

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

Negate one of the features, start over, and use what you know about positively correlated variables! – whuber
( But negating will change the actual data, doesn't it?  – Ankit Seth )
Sure--but it's no different than, say, recording temperatures in degrees F and restating them in degrees C for analysis. Besides, you're doing ML--why would you even care that the data are changed, provided the model works? – whuber